# How to set pyspark default context in jupyter notebooks?

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

When I launch my pyspark setup, it creates a Jupyter notebook which I can happily access on the web. It also automatically creates objects such as 'sc' and 'spark' - contexts. Where can I override how these objects are initialised?

Answer (score 2):

Start pure python kernel in jupyter. Then add environment variables for spark and pyspark and prepend `sys.path` with pyspark libs, for example:

```
import os, sys
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = '/home/mario/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7'
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--master local[2] --driver-memory 2g pyspark-shell"
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = '/usr/bin/python3'
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/mario/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip')
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/mario/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python')
```

Then you can customize spark initialization inside jupyter cell, for example:

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
spark = (SparkSession.builder
    .appName('picapica')
    .config('spark.speculation', 'true')
    .getOrCreate())
```